# How to remove menu's from html during crawl or indexing with nutch and solr

Tags: solr, nutch

We are using Nutch 2.1 with solr 4.8.1 and want to remove header and footer from  the parsed result. 
We have tried element-selector plugin (https://github.com/kaqqao/nutch-element-selector) to remove header and footer but there is no effect in our search result.

can anyone help to get sort this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in nutch site.xml

```
<!-- tika properties to use BoilerPipe, according to Marcus Jelsma --> 
<property> 
  <name>tika.use_boilerpipe</name> 
  <value>true</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>tika.boilerpipe.extractor</name> 
  <value>ArticleExtractor</value> 
</property>
```

This wont exactly remove header and footer, but it will do a decent job in removing things other than main article in the page.

If you are not satisfied you can use other boilerplates like https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/